# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions

Tags: c#

I posted a question about this code yesterday, but I did it... really badly. I've since talked with a friend of mine who knows coding very well and tried a few things, but I've genuinely hit a wall with this. I tried looking at other questions of the same accord, but none of their solutions worked for me...

What I am trying to do is overwrite "effectiveness". The server is taking the effectiveness as 4 or 5 (I am not sure which, but it's definitely one of the two-- It doesn't matter which, anyway). I want it to take it as 7 or above. I figured out how to call effectiveness data from the server, but it still doesn't seem to be working. 4/5 effectiveness gives me the text "It's not very effective...", which keeps happening when I try to use the code.

This is my code (There is a lot more to it, but I have removed what is irrelevant):

```
public partial class Main {
    public static int effectiveness;
    public static void BeforeMoveHits(BattleSetup setup) {
        try {
            if (setup.Defender != null) {
                switch (setup.Move.AdditionalEffectData3) {
                    case 69: { //Freeze Dry
                            if (setup.Defender.Type1 == Enums.PokemonType.Water ||
                                setup.Defender.Type2 == Enums.PokemonType.Water) {  
                                DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[256];
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                     }
                 }
         }
    }
}
```

As stated in the tile, when I try to compile it, I get the error

> only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

The

```
public static int effectiveness
```

is left over from when I tried using "effectiveness = 8" as opposed to DamageCalculator.Effectiveness. Removing it affects nothing, so I've left it there in case I need it later.

In DamageCalculator.cs, this is what sets effectiveness:

```
public static int[] Effectiveness = new int[9] {2, 8, 16, 64, 96, 160, 256, 416, 640};
```

You can view the full code [here](https://github.com/pmdcp/Server/blob/6ccc1935670a0f86eea8e6504d9fec67b241f710/Server/Combat/DamageCalculator.cs) if you find it helpful.

There's also a tidbit of info about effectiveness in BattleProcessor.cs, though I doubt its relevancy as I continue to work on this...

```
    public static string EffectivenessToPhrase(int effectiveness) {
        if (effectiveness < 4) {
            return "It has little effect...";
        } else if (effectiveness < 6) {
            return "It's not very effective...";
        } else if (effectiveness == 7) {
            return "It's super-effective!";

        } else if (effectiveness > 7) {
            return "It's super-effective!!!";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[This](https://github.com/pmdcp/Server/blob/6ccc1935670a0f86eea8e6504d9fec67b241f710/Server/Combat/BattleProcessor.cs) is the full code of BattleProcessor.cs, if you need it.

It's worth noting that I can*not* change BeforeMoveHits from void, and I can*not* change Main to anything besides partial. Doing so will break other parts of the game this is for. That being said, if changing effectiveness isn't possible because of these circumstances, just tell me. I'll... try to figure out something else to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaning to statement

```
DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[256];
```

this statement is returning a value which you are not using at all.
you need at a least to save the value which you return in some variable to use it later. Or why you really doing this.

the following statement will solve the compile time error.

```
var temp = DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[256];
```

BTW the

```
DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[256];
```

will thrown an exception after you make the code could be compiled.
The exception will be `IndexOutOfRangeException`
and at that time solve this problem by the following statement

```
DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[6]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. It's still making the effectiveness be less than 6. Thank you for telling me about the out of range thing and the no meaning thing, though!

Answer (score 1):

Your statement "Damagecalculator.effectiveness[256]" makes no sense. You don't define or assign anything here. I think that's why the compiler complains. You're using the array wrong. Just use a simple integer to set the effectiveness. If you want the effectiveness to be set at this specific numbers, you should use enumerators.

Comment: Pardon, I'm a newbie-- What do you mean by integer? Do you mean something like "int effectiveness"? Because if so, that doesn't work. I've already tried and exhausted it. And, what do you mean by "use enumerators"? Again, sorry, I'm really new to C#...

Comment: @Foxwells Yes, I mean using int effectiveness. Then set the effectiveness to how effective the move was: effectiveness = 256; Here is the documentation about enumerators: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

Comment: int effectiveness doesn't work. The battle log still calls the move not very effective. Thank you for the link, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you linked for `BattleProcessor` class is actually mostly commented as I see it, then you can

- exploit its  `EffectivenessToPhrase()` method passing it a sufficiently high `effectiveness` parameter

  ```
  string effectivenessToPhrase =  BattleProcessor.EffectivenessToPhrase(7);
  ```

  this would only affect the *ToPrhase* output
- change `Effectiveness[]` values so as to mimic higher indexes:

  ```
  DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[4]=256;
  DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[5]=256;
  ```

  this would affect whatever code will be using `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness`

  then you must get those values back to original ones (respectively, 96 and 160) as soon as your task is accomplished

Comment: The thing is, I can't edit those files. Those are server files which are kept by the game's founder. I only have access to a very small portion of the coding. That said... Is there a way I could make it say its effectiveness is 7 and then just do a damage multiplier to get the affect of 7 effectiveness?

Comment: my answer solutions don't require any editing of those classes since both `EffectivenessToPhrase()` method and `Effectiveness[]` array are declared as `Public`. So you just type those pieces of code in your `BeforeMoveHits()` method.

Comment: Hmm... Changing the damagecalculator seemed to work, but effectivenesstophrase didn't do anything. It still says the move is not very effective.

Comment: since, as you now specified, you need the _"damage multiplier to get the affect of 7 effectiveness"_, then the `change Effectiveness[] values` part of my answer should do (and the warning apply, too!) . This way you'll affect the `dmg *= DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[effectiveness];` statement in `BattleProcessor ` class, while for subsequent `dmg *= setup.Multiplier` statement you also have to access `setup.Multiplier` property

Comment: No no, I /don't/ need the damage multiplier to be upped. That works fine. My issue is that in the battle log, where it says the phrases of effectiveness, it still shows up as not very effective http://prntscr.com/cu2b50 -- Unless I misunderstood what you said? You lost me a bit there.

Comment: Changing `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[]` array works because it happens to be actually used by the _real_ damage calculator method. While my `effectivenessToPhrase` proposal was a way to artificially get a "wanted" phrase from the `BattleProcessor.EffectivenessToPhrase()` public method. But, of course, whoever is still  _saying_ "the move is not very effective" is using that same method but passing it an `effectiveness` value calculated in a way that doesn't use `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[]` array. So you either get the class/method responsible for that "saying" or you stay as you are

Comment: Hm... So you're saying I need to look for whatever calculator is deciding effectiveness but not using damagecalculator.effectiveness? Just asking for clarification.

Comment: Since your last bother is about the "phrase", you just need to look for _who_'s uttering it. The mots probable culprit is a class that calls `BattleProcessor.EffectivenessToPhrase()`.

Comment: Except I did your suggestion of changing battleprocessor.effectivenesstophrase, and it didn't do anything.

Comment: I don't get you: what did you change and where? If you're saying you just put `string effectivenessToPhrase =  BattleProcessor.EffectivenessToPhrase(7);` in your `BeforeMoveHits()` method, then it _isn't_ supposed to do anything but store a proper phrase in `effectivenessToPhrase` string for your subsequent uses. Look: place a breakpoint at the line with `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[4]=256;
` and then step though the code line by line to see what statement causes the _saying_: "the move is not very effective"

Comment: I copy/pasted your codes and put them under case 69. All of this is supposed to be specific to case 69-- I don't want anything else affected.

Comment: place a breakpoint at the line with DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[4]=256;  and then step though the code line by line to see what statement causes the saying: "the move is not very effective"

Comment: I'm unable to do that. I don't own the server files outside of a very small portion. That, and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: when you are in visual studio select the line with `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[4]=256` and press F9. Then run your program, when it'll stop at that line you keep pressing F11 to step through each subsequent line and see where you're jumping

Comment: I'm not using visual studio. I'm using the in-game script editor. My laptop can't handle VS. I might have a friend who does, though?

Comment: Hope so. In the meanwhile, you may want to mark my answer as accepted since it both corrected the error and had you _overwrite "effectiveness"_ for its substantial part. thank you

Comment: Except that it failed to do so and I'm now using a bizarre workaround method that sets a Pokemon's type to Flying then immediately takes it away after being hit because I grew impatient and your answer was dizzingly confusing.

Comment: so _"Changing the damagecalculator seemed to work,"_ wasn't true?

Comment: It was true, but I didn't really need the help with the damage calculator. I already knew how to get the damage to how I wanted. My main issue was that it kept showing "its not very effective", and to that your answer didn't solve.

Comment: Your post was about (and named after) an "error". My answer resolved it by saying you had to use `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[4]=256;` where you typed `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[256];`. And that's all. As per this site rules I answered your question. If you want to stay in SO you have to follow its rules, which I'd recommend you to read carefully.

Comment: none of those answers those told you to use `DamageCalculator.Effectiveness[4]=256` as mine did. I also happened to be the only answerer who tried helping you along further elaborations while others didn't. Now, since you couldn't have all those other things done you are accepting an answer which you yourself commented with _"Unfortunately, this didn't work. It's still making the effectiveness be less than 6"_  to "punish" me. Well that's really interesting matter for _very_ clever psychiatrists